# Data parcel size error when init video player

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-video-player

i have to app with video player, when i select one item in the list, I open a new activity, in this activity receive one intent with value string and later initialize a fragment, there is have video player, when start video, the app is closed because have data parcel size error, i dont know reason launch show this error.

```
> > FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                  Process: com.msi.eluniversal, PID: 969
>                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException:
> data parcel size 689244 bytes
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3752)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                                                                   Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size
> 689244 bytes
>                                                                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
>                                                                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
>                                                                      at
> android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3606)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3744)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                      at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly passing too much data in the `startActivity()` intent. You are limited to passing 1MiB due to the fixed binder buffer size. Also consider that the buffer is for all binder transactions in your process so if you are performing some other IPC that'll eat into the buffer.

You should really never pass large chunks of data. If you need to "pass" such things, pass a reference to them (e.g., a file path, or a content URI where they can be retrieved).

Comment: only share one value is string inside intent, when start activity and later don`t send more values, y don't use transitions with material design

Comment: Something you doing in your activity is passing a parcel of size 689244 it's right there in your logs. Hard to say what it is since you did not post any code.

Comment: sorry, i don share code in post, because characters in the code not permited  in limit in the post